# Chrome not displaying Bootstrap3 properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

Folks,
  The following code does not render the dropdown menu in Chrome (latest), but works fine in Safari.

Suggestions?

```
    nav(role="navigation").navbar.navbar-default
    .navbar-header
        button(type="button", data-toggle="collapse", data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse").navbar-toggle
            span.sr-only Toggle navigation
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
            span.icon-bar
        a(href="#" ).navbar-brand Baz
    .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-ex1-collapse
        ul.nav.navbar-nav 
            li.active: a(href="/foo/") FOO
            li: a(href="/bar/") BAR
        ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
            li.dropdown
                a(href="#", data-toggle="dropdown").dropdown-toggle dropdown <b class="caret"></b>
                ul.dropdown-menu
                    li: a(href="/asdf") asdf
                    li: a(href="#") XYZ
p
```

Answer (score 1):

Folks,
  Naturally answer to most problems is obvious.  Inspect the page, figure out that Chrome prevents non-ssl links from ssl pages. Fix the jquery to load before bootstrap

Done